# Dynamically get different colors while building stacked bar graph in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to read a csv file in D3 and trying to build stacked bar graphs with 2 attributes,  in the csv file I don't know how many unique values exist for a particular attribute. So depending on number of unique attributes I need that many different colors to draw stacked bar graph.

Is there any way to get different colors given an integer `n` like 10 or 15 in D3 or javascript?

Comment: read https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic, use the sequential colors or sample the rainbow scemes n times using a scaleLinear

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following approach:

```
function generatePallete(n) {
  const scale = t => d3.interpolateSinebow(t * 0.85);
  return d3.range(n).map(i => scale(i / n))
}
```

You can replace `d3.interpolateSinebow` with any other sequential scale. I multiplied `t` by `0.85` because `d3.interpolateSinebow` is cyclical and start end end colors are the same.

Here is an example of generated palletes:

[image]